# Plugin settings page in CP styling

Tags: plugin-development, css

I'm having issues finding out what all the classes are Craft uses to style its control panel.

I have extended the layout but is there any place with more information about what classed there are and how to use them?

Answer (score 2):

[Plugin UXD](https://github.com/putyourlightson/craft-plugin-uxd) is intended to help you "design" one or more control panel pages in Craft. It is not a complete style guide but provides a set of typography, field and table elements that enables you to quickly design and develop your plugin control panel pages.

As the developer, I'll gladly accept pull requests to make it more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is not a Control Panel style guide available.

I think your best bet currently would be to inspect the source code as well as exiting plugins that have extended Craft's Control Panel templates to see how they do it.